# Increasing threads in Undertow server

Tags: java, redhat, amazon-elb, undertow

I am working with Undertow and my aim is to get maximum throughput using aws instances.

The issue I am facing is:

When I use one instance with threads = 1000, I get a throughout of 9900.
When I use two instances with threads = 1000 (each), I get a throughput of 9800.

One of the ways I thought is to increase the number of threads while creating the server.

This is the error I get:

```
        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
            at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:141)
            at testProject.testArtifact.ServerConnection.createServer(ServerConnection.java:63)
            at testProject.testArtifact.App.main(App.java:20)
            ... 6 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.makePipe(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:65)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36)
            at org.xnio.nio.NioXnio$DefaultSelectorCreator.open(NioXnio.java:245)
            at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.<init>(NioXnioWorker.java:93)
            at org.xnio.nio.NioXnio.createWorker(NioXnio.java:203)
            at org.xnio.Xnio.createWorker(Xnio.java:437)
            at org.xnio.Xnio.createWorker(Xnio.java:424)
            at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:84)
            ... 8 more
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 1.938 s
        [INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-24T17:31:59+00:00
        [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/142M
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java (default-cli) on project testArtifact: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files -> [Help 1]
        org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java (default-cli) on project testArtifact: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
            at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:345)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
            ... 19 more
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
            at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:141)
            at testProject.testArtifact.ServerConnection.createServer(ServerConnection.java:63)
            at testProject.testArtifact.App.main(App.java:20)
            ... 6 more
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.makePipe(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(EPollSelectorImpl.java:65)
            at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(EPollSelectorProvider.java:36)
            at org.xnio.nio.NioXnio$DefaultSelectorCreator.open(NioXnio.java:245)
            at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.<init>(NioXnioWorker.java:93)
            at org.xnio.nio.NioXnio.createWorker(NioXnio.java:203)
            at org.xnio.Xnio.createWorker(Xnio.java:437)
            at org.xnio.Xnio.createWorker(Xnio.java:424)
            at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:84)
            ... 8 more
        [ERROR]
        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
        [ERROR]
        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How can I increase the throughput in my case.

I am not able to resolve the issue when I try to use threads > 1000

Any help wold be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the number of open files on your operating system. On Linux this is typically configured in limits.conf/limits.d

Comment: ..or by typing `ulimit -n #` for open files or `ulimit -u #` for number of processes. But these settings don't survive the restart, so the above is better, but you can tune the values this way.